# C# HtmlAgilityPack Html Load external

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm using HtmlAgilityPack to get html from a site and the requests from that site are made by XMLHttpRequest and the html are loaded in a DIV i can't get that html loaded external by request i tried, but i can't get the html

```
                HttpWebRequest getRequest = WebRequest.Create(Url) as HttpWebRequest;
            //
            getRequest.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
            getRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
            getRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0";
            getRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
            getRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
            getRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            getRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            Stream newStream1 = getRequest.GetRequestStream();
            newStream1.Close();
            HttpWebResponse getRequestResponse = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse();
            string source = "";

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getRequestResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.Default))
            {
                source = sr.ReadToEnd();
                //Console.WriteLine(source);
            }
            doc.LoadHtml(source);
            getRequestResponse.Close();
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? -- Are you expecting it to execute the JavaScript/AJAX requests on a given page?  Because the `HtmlAgilityPack` doesn't do that, it's not a web browser, it just parses HTML that you give it into a DOM. -- If you want to do screen scraping, I recommend looking into web browser automation with `Selenium` (it should be on Nuget). -- Try it out with Firefox or Chrome to get started / debug, but then you should be able to move to the PhantomJS headless browser to avoid showing UI / increase the performance.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend updating your code to use the HttpClient class. This has support for async behaviour which can help with scalability of your application (in some cases).

[MSDN HttpClient Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

However, looking at the current implementation, if you are receiving a 405 error it may be because you are trying to POST to the URL. Since I can see no POST data in the code snippet you have shown, it might be better to use a GET request:

```
getRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
```